# Minecraft fishing problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Luck of the Sea III,Lure II, mending and unbreaking II. I have AFK fished for over 10 hours (leaving it on during the day and sometimes all through the night) and still haven’t gotten a single enchanted item or any other “treasure” item. I use a note block with a iron trap door and a weighted pressure plate in my station. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The fishing mechanics were changed heavily in Java 1.16, nerfing the previous simple designs of AFK fish farms. As the [Junk and Treasure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing#Junk_and_treasure) section of the Fishing wiki notes:

> To catch items in the treasure category, the bobber must be in open water, defined as the 5×4×5 vicinity around the bobber resting on the water surface (2 blocks away horizontally, 2 blocks above the water surface, and 2 blocks deep). Each horizontal layer in this area must consist only of air and lily pads or water source blocks, waterlogged blocks without collision (such as signs, kelp, or coral), and bubble columns. These conditions are checked every tick to determine if the player is eligible to receive treasure from a fishing attempt. If the conditions are not met, only items in the fish and junk categories can be obtained from fishing.

If you are playing 1.16 or above, please check out the new farm designs. They require more resources and though AFK fishing may not be as useful as it was in previous versions, you can still do it.